# API Request timeout issue

Tags: angularjs, node.js, rest, api, http

I am calling one post API which will give me a response after a certain period of time after completing its job. That job is taking time to complete and I am getting timeout error in the API response.
Can anyone help me resolve this? Is there anything I have to set before calling the API which will keep my API call alive until it gets the response? Thanks in advance.

I tried below solutions but didn't worked for me

- In http post call set header "Connection":"keep-alive"
- Used timeout property but still didn't worked

Answer (score 0):

Please set *timeout* value for *keep-alive*. Only setting connection type will not work in this scenario. You should set the properties of keep-alive. Try your luck and let me know if any query.

Answer (score 0):

Pass in a [`config`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http/#usage) argument when you make your call. Set its `timeout` property to more milliseconds than you expect the response to take.